# PHP Ratchet websocket doesn't work on SSL connection

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, ratchet

here's my Ratchet server file

```
<?php 
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use ChatWebSocket\Application;
require 'Application.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Application()
        )
    ),
    2020
);
$server->run();
```

And this is Client side using WS Javascript to connect

```
(function(){
    var conn = new WebSocket('wss://mydomain.net:2020');

    conn.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Connection OK!");
    };

    conn.onmessage = function(e) {
        var res = JSON.parse(e.data);
        alert(res);

    };
})();
```

when i turn off SSL mode (http:// connect) and using `ws://mydomain.net:2020` then the server works fine!

And when i turn on SSL mode, connect to server with `wss://mydomain.net:2020`, go to client web with `https://` then i get this error from console

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.net:2020/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

i've tried add this setting to my `httpd.conf` file

```
ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://mydomain.net:2020/
```

but i got same error.

how can i fix this error? how to connect websocket with SSL (https://) ?

Comment: I think you are actually  aware of this duplicate and tried to use it. But, look closer which URL should be used with wss:// and you will see that it is using the default port of wss:// and not the port where the ws:// server is on. That's because it first connects with https to Apache (default port) which then *internally* forwards the traffic to the ws:// proxy - after stripping the TLS layer.

Comment: Thank you! But when i turn on ssl i also i replace ws:// to wss:// to try it on https. But failed!

Comment: To cite myself: *"...look closer ... you will see that it is using the default port of wss://..."*. Thus, don't use `wss://mydomain.net:2020/` as you do but use `wss://mydomain.net/`, i.e. omit the port number so that it uses the default 443 where Apache is listening on and where it is forwarding the non-TLS traffic to `ws://mydomain.net:2020/`. And don't try to use `https://` instead of `wss://` because the first is for normal secure HTTP traffic and the other for secure websockets.